# Is there a way to repeat a li class 'x' amount of times?

Tags: php, html

I am hopeful there is a way to greatly improve my bit of code.

I have a li class which I need to repeat 'x' amount of times based on a php variable.

I am getting around this at the moment by using a nested IF statement but surely there is a cleaner way?

```
if ($pTotal == 5) {?>
<div class="point-container">
  <div class="row">
    <ul class="score">
      <li class='points'></li>
      <li class='points'></li>
      <li class='points'></li>
      <li class='points'></li>
      <li class='points'></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<?php } elseif ($pTotal == 6) { ?>
<div class="point-container">
  <div class="row">
    <ul class="score">
      <li class='points'></li>
      <li class='points'></li>
      <li class='points'></li>
      <li class='points'></li>
      <li class='points'></li>
      <li class='points'></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<?php } elseif ($pTotal == 7) { ?>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Why not use a `for` loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily use [`str_repeat()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-repeat.php) to repeat the same chunk of text for a specific number of times...

```
$div = '<div class="point-container">
    <div class="row">
      <ul class="score">';
$div .= str_repeat("<li class='points'></li>", $pTotal);
$div .="</ul></div></div>";
echo $div;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php function printLi(int $pTotal) { ?>
    <div class="point-container">
        <div class="row">
            <ul class="score">
                <?php for ($i = 0; $i < $pTotal; $i++): ?>
                    <li class='points'></li>
                <?php endfor; ?> 
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php } ?>

<?php printLi($pTotal);
```

Comment: I can't spot it but there must be a syntax error here as it stops the page loading.

Comment: That also works perfectly, thank you.  Are you able to explain (unbiassly) the pros and cons of each solution?

Comment: these approaches are different, but they do the same thing. But you have to choose the one that suits you best